# Android Studio AssembleRelease error when trying to generate apk via the command line

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I'm trying to generate an apk via the command line, as I need to send my apk to a Jenkins conveyor belt. When I try to generate the apk through the Android Studio interface, it generates correctly, however when I try to generate it through the Android Studio terminal itself, I get BUILD FAILED.
I've looked a lot and tried a few things to find a solution but without success and the answers on this subject are old, so nothing worked for me.

[gradle assembleRelease via interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk4lQ.png)
[gradle assembleRelease via interface BUILD SUCCESSFUL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhzBq.png)

```
./gradlew clean build assembleRelease
```

when I use the command

```
./gradlew clean build assembleRelease
```

in the terminal I get the error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mycompany:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mycompany:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0d320b4034ab2cb8993658e30dc7e288/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0d320b4034ab2cb8993658e30dc7e288/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
```

```
java -version
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.1 (Eclipse Adoptium 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.2.1 x86_64
```

[Gradle JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjNzZ.png)
[Gradle Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvCj4.png)

build.gradle(:app)

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.3.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    namespace 'com.mycompany'

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.grade(project)

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '8.1.2'
        agp_version1 = '8.1.1'
        agp_version2 = '8.1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version2"
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I updated the gradle and jdk version, but without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, i added more details from the gradle files.